# USB DAC not recognized

Tags: sound, usb, pulseaudio

I get this from `sudo dmesg` as soon as I plug my Fiio BTR5 into my Ubuntu machine:

```
[209210.911137] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 96
[209217.493244] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 97 using xhci_hcd
[209217.650464] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2972, idProduct=0047, bcdDevice= 0.2e
[209217.650474] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=3, SerialNumber=0
[209217.650477] usb 3-1: Product: FiiO BTR5
[209217.650480] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: FiiO
[209222.673444] usb 3-1: 1:1: cannot set freq 384000 (v2/v3): err -110
[209222.675092] usb 3-1: parse_audio_format_rates_v2v3(): unable to find clock source (clock -71)
[209222.675446] usb 3-1: uac_clock_source_is_valid(): cannot get clock validity for id 41
[209222.675449] usb 3-1: clock source 41 is not valid, cannot use
[209222.676773] usb 3-1: 1:3 : unsupported format bits 0x100000000
[209222.676950] usb 3-1: parse_audio_format_rates_v2v3(): unable to find clock source (clock -71)
[209222.677289] usb 3-1: uac_clock_source_is_valid(): cannot get clock validity for id 41
[209222.677293] usb 3-1: clock source 41 is not valid, cannot use
[209222.730441] usb 3-1: 1:0: usb_set_interface failed (-71)
[209222.730615] usb 3-1: uac_clock_source_is_valid(): cannot get clock validity for id 41
[209222.730618] usb 3-1: clock source 41 is not valid, cannot use
[209222.730985] usb 3-1: 1:0: usb_set_interface failed (-71)
[209222.731175] usb 3-1: 1:0: usb_set_interface failed (-71)
[209222.731337] usb 3-1: uac_clock_source_is_valid(): cannot get clock validity for id 41
[209222.731338] usb 3-1: clock source 41 is not valid, cannot use
[209222.731654] usb 3-1: 1:0: usb_set_interface failed (-71)
[209222.731851] usb 3-1: 1:0: usb_set_interface failed (-71)
[209222.732000] usb 3-1: uac_clock_source_is_valid(): cannot get clock validity for id 41
[209222.732001] usb 3-1: clock source 41 is not valid, cannot use
[209222.732300] usb 3-1: 1:0: usb_set_interface failed (-71)
[209222.732550] usb 3-1: 1:0: usb_set_interface failed (-71)
[209222.732698] usb 3-1: uac_clock_source_is_valid(): cannot get clock validity for id 41
[209222.732699] usb 3-1: clock source 41 is not valid, cannot use
[209222.733013] usb 3-1: 1:0: usb_set_interface failed (-71)
[209222.733248] usb 3-1: 1:0: usb_set_interface failed (-71)
[209222.733408] usb 3-1: uac_clock_source_is_valid(): cannot get clock validity for id 41
[209222.733410] usb 3-1: clock source 41 is not valid, cannot use
[209222.733754] usb 3-1: 1:0: usb_set_interface failed (-71)
[209222.734327] usb 3-1: 1:0: usb_set_interface failed (-71)
[209222.734533] usb 3-1: uac_clock_source_is_valid(): cannot get clock validity for id 41
[209222.734540] usb 3-1: clock source 41 is not valid, cannot use
[209222.734968] usb 3-1: 1:0: usb_set_interface failed (-71)
[209222.735395] usb 3-1: 1:0: usb_set_interface failed (-71)
[209222.735585] usb 3-1: uac_clock_source_is_valid(): cannot get clock validity for id 41
[209222.735589] usb 3-1: clock source 41 is not valid, cannot use
[209222.736134] usb 3-1: 1:0: usb_set_interface failed (-71)
[209222.736363] usb 3-1: 1:0: usb_set_interface failed (-71)
```

Any idea why this is happening? Thanks

Comment: Same with Yamaha USB DAC. Happens a lot with latest kernel versions (not LTS). Only way for me to get it recognized is to unplug/plug USB cable. Maybe it has to do with usb modules. Anyone?

Comment: @AlexanderG. What's the XMOS chip in your Yamaha USB DAC? I tested a couple of DACs and it seems models with XUF208 don't work while the ones with XU316 work fine. The sample size is small so I am not 100% sure.